# Is it easy to get the UK tourist visa again after expiring?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

My UK tourist visa has expired. Is it easy to get the visa extended, or will they investigate me to the same degree as the first time I applied? I have an Indian passport 
and I crossed the UK border twice this year.

My intent to visit the UK is only for tourist purposes and meeting friends.

Comment: If you already had a visa and never overstayed, then you're more likely to be approved for another one, provided your circumstances have not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon what you wrote, you are building up a history of performance and this will work in your favour.  More so as time goes on...

While our laws **theoretically** allow you to apply for visitor visas back-to-back, they added a new rule two years ago that prohibits building up a life in the UK by frequent/successive visits, and so if they think that you are attempting to build up a life in the UK, you will be vulnerable to a refusal.  The wording and interpretation of the rule is purposefully vague.

For your question:  "Is it easier"?  The answer is that **it does not matter**.  It is a dreadful mistake to assume too much in a UK visa application regardless of your history.  Each application should start from first principles and assume that there is no preceding history. Plan for the full 90 days processing time. When your history (along with application quality) satisfies the ECO, he will automatically get back to you and ask if you prefer a visa with longer tenure, like a 2 year etc.  It is his decision and there is nothing you can do to promote it or persuade him.